# jquery-confirm - submit clicked button in form with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using [this](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) very nice Jquery confirm plugin, problem is I am having issue with submit specific button in form with multiple buttons, my code works fine in `php side` without `jquery-confirm` plugin. It can get exact button submit value but I want to get confirmation before submit. Below is my scenario:

I have 2 delete submit buttons in single form and integrated with jquery-confirm. When I click on specific delete button (18), it submit the whole form, what I wanted is only the clicked button allowed to submit, below is my code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="messages">
<button type="submit" name="message_id" value="18" class="btn btn-danger confirmation" >Delete</button>

<button type="submit" name="message_id" value="17" class="btn btn-danger confirmation" >Delete</button>
</form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('.confirmation').confirm({
        content: 'Delete this message?',
        title: 'Please confirm',
        confirm: function(){
            $('#messages :submit').submit();
        }
    });
```

So far, I have tried with `this.$target.closest('#messages').submit();`, with trigger('click')  but they weren't working as expected.

If i add `onclick="return confirm('Delete this message?');"` inside `button`, it will trigger alert box and submit the selected button as expected, not the whole form submission. what I wanted is to get the value of the submitted button only, from PHP side when the button submitted. When I click on specific delete button ( value 18), I can catch the `$_POST['message_id']` value = 18 without `jquery-confirm` plugin. But when I use `jquery-confirm` with `submit()`, from PHP side it could not catch any `$_POST['message_id']` value .

See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr48nq63/4/) for more details:

Comment: So you are trying to make only one button prompt?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on _When I click on specific delete button (18), it submit the whole form, what I wanted is only the clicked button allowed to submit_

Comment: can you post jquery code with click of the delete button and confirmation? If before your confirmation code is the click event please post it.

Comment: what I want is to get the value of the submitted button only, from PHP side when the button submitted. When I click on specific delete button ( value 18), I can catch the $_POST['message_id'] value = 18 without jquery-confirm plugin. But when I use jquery-confirm with submit(), from PHP side it could not catch any $_POST['message_id'] value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround is to add hidden input with clicked message_id value, so everything is works fine for now, posted here in case of anyone else need this :

```
$('.confirmation').confirm({
        content: 'Delete this message?',
        title: 'Please confirm',
        confirm: function(){
            $('<input>').attr('type','hidden').attr('name', 'message_id').attr('value', this.$target.val()).appendTo('form');
            $('#messages').submit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach.

```
$('button[type=submit]').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // prevent submit button from firing and submit form
var $this = $(this);   
$('.confirmation').confirm({
        content: 'Delete this message?',
        title: 'Please confirm',
        confirm: function(){
           $this.parent('form').submit(); // since user has confirmed action now submit form
        }
    });
});
```

**OR**

Create a small delete.php file where you can place the php code that handles the deletion of the message.

Use jQuery `post()` to submit your data after confirmation.

```
    $('button[type=submit]').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent submit button from firing and submit form
        var $this = $(this);   
        $('.confirmation').confirm({
                content: 'Delete this message?',
                title: 'Please confirm',
                confirm: function(){
                         $.post( "delete.php", { message_id: $this.val() })
                         .done(function() {
                          alert( "second success" );
                          })
                          .fail(function() {
                          alert( "error" );
                          });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi Peter,
Thanks for helpful answer, but I dont want to over complicated this via $.post nor $.ajax, just a simple confirmation when user click ok then it will submit the form to the PHP side :)

Comment: can you confirm what is posted when using example A in my answer? @SonDang, i mean can you echo what is being posted?

Comment: I tried your first example as well, but it was not working too. But I have found a workaround for this is add hidden input with clicked message_id value then everything work fine :)